# Youtube video downloader for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiwebview, youtube

I need to create a downloaded application for iPhone. Many of application is already in itune with same purpose. When any video play in UIWebView player, then i have to show option for downloading video. For downloading video i need URL which is playing in Player.

What i tried yet

i have found nothing, i got Notification which tell me that player is in full screen or not (UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification).  I have tried with web view delegate methods for URL but it is not giving me any video URL. it print on console "setting movie path:"  but it is not giving full path for downlaod

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: post your code. Hard to "imagine" what your code does (or doesn't).